# How to center this input using css only

Tags: html, css

I have an **input area:**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Here" class="input" name="input[]"/>
```

And its **css:**

```
<style>
.input{padding-left:13px;margin-left:12px;padding-top:10px;border:0px;width:65%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Marker Felt", "Segoe Print",sans-serif;background:url(http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/836/framebackground.png);display:block;border-radius:10px;}
.input:hover{box-shadow:0 0 25px #0093ff;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #0093ff;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #0093ff}
</style>
```

I want to make this input on the center of my page with using css only i mean I dont want to use div around them to center them I tried using `text-align:center;` in `body` but it didn't worked I am using `<center>` but according to w3c its removed since HTML 4 so i want to do this using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

**CSS**

```
<style>
.input{padding-left:13px;margin-left:12px;padding-top:10px;border:0px;width:65%;font-size:15px;font-family:"Marker Felt", "Segoe Print",sans-serif;background:url(http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/836/framebackground.png);display:block;border-radius:10px;margin:0 auto;}
.input:hover{box-shadow:0 0 25px #0093ff;-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 25px #0093ff;-moz-box-shadow:0 0 25px #0093ff}
</style>
```

Here you can use `margin:0 auto;` to center your input element.

**HTML:**

`<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Here" class="input" name="input[]"/>`

Comment: a) you should explain what you did instead of just dumping a block of code as an answer. b) how is your answer different from  mine?

Comment: a)Thanks for your advice.
b)Hmmm yes but before posting i didn't knew this has already been posted .

Answer (score 3):

Add `margin:0 auto;` to your `.input` class.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eU9QW/)

(and good for you for not using `<center>`)